# I want to group by the below SQL query by pv.name, which is giving error. Any alternatives?

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT pv.id, SUM(pv.unit_for_inventory), pv.name from order_items oi left join orders o on oi.order_id = o.id left join product_variants pv on oi.product_variant_id = pv.id where o.status = 'DELIVERED' GROUP by pv.id ORDER BY pv.name[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8PNp.png)

in the above image, there are multiple records of the same name, it should be grouped together

Comment: And the error message is ?!

Answer (score 0):

Group by all unaggregated columns:

```
select pv.id, SUM(pv.unit_for_inventory), pv.name
from order_items oi join
     orders o
     on oi.order_id = o.id left join
     product_variants pv 
     on oi.product_variant_id = pv.id
where o.status = 'DELIVERED' 
group by pv.id, pv.name 
order by pv.name;
```

Note that the `left join` to `orders` is definitely not required because the `where` clause requires a match.  You probably don't want a `left join` to `product_variants` either.